# Cypress route function not detecting the network request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e2e-testing, cypress

I'm trying to wait for a request made by my application but Cypress is not detecting it on `cy.wait`

```
    cy.server();
    cy.getAuthenticatedUrl();
    cy.route('POST', '/showroom/validate').as('uploadShowroom');

    cy.get('[data-testid=Next]').click();

    cy.uploadFile('[id=uploadArea]', 'testfile-valid.xlsx', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');

    cy.wait('@uploadShowroom');

    cy.contains('FILE UPLOAD DONE');
```

If I check my console during the tests, I can see that the request was made to my server

[image: screenshot-console]

Both my client and my server are running local but in different ports.

The error is the following:
`CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: 'uploadShowroom'. No request ever occurred.`

Comment: Does the route show up the same in the cypress command log?  And does it show up before the timeout error is thrown?

Comment: @Brendan yes, the second screenshot is from the cypress log (logged a few seconds before the timeout)

Comment: That doesn't look like the command log.  I'm talking about the command log in the test runner: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-runner.html .  I'm guessing the request isn't an XHR as Richard Matsen mentions in his answer.  If it is an XHR it'll show up in the command log, if it isn't, it won't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is because your form is using native form submit, but Cypress' `cy.route()` only responds to XHR calls (at the moment).

There is a big discussion in [issue #170](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/170).

Gleb Bahmutov has an interesting idea in this [comment](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/170#issuecomment-358527017), code in this [repository](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-form-data-with-file-upload). Essentially he 'mocks' the native submit with an XHR submit, on the fly.

I tried out a variation which gets closer to your scenario. Follow the repository READ.ME to set up the test, but first update the Cypress version in `package.json`. Add the file to be uploaded into `/cypress/fixtures`.

Then try the following spec.

The third test is an alternative which uses `cy.url()` instead of `cy.route()`.

**uploadFile command (or similar variation)**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('uploadFile', (fileName, selector) =>
  cy.get(selector).then(subject => {
    return cy
      .fixture(fileName, 'base64')
      .then(Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob)
      .then(blob => {
        const el = subject[0];
        const testFile = new File([blob], fileName, {
          type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        });
        const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
        dataTransfer.items.add(testFile);
        el.files = dataTransfer.files;
        return subject;
      });
  })
);
```

**Function to 'mock' the native submit with XHR (place at top of Spec)**

```js
const mockNativeSubmitWithXhr = (form$) => {
  let win
  cy.window().then(w => {
    win = w
  })
  form$.on('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const form = new FormData(e.target)
    const XHR = new win.XMLHttpRequest()
    XHR.onload = response => {
      win.document.write(XHR.responseText)
      win.history.pushState({}, '', XHR.url)
    }
    XHR.open(e.target.method, e.target.action)
    XHR.send(form)
    return true
  })
}
```

**Spec**

```js
describe('waiting for form-data post', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.task('deleteFile', '../../uploads/Sample_data.xlsx')
    cy.visit('localhost:3000')
    cy.get('input[name="userid"]').type('foo@bar.com')
  })

  it('upload with native form submit (fails because of native event)', () => {
    cy.server()
    cy.route('POST', '/upload').as('upload');

    cy.uploadFile('Sample_data.xlsx', '[id=fileToUpload]')
    cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()

    cy.wait('@upload');
    cy.readFile('uploads/Sample_data.xlsx') // check saved file
  })

  it('upload with form submit mocked to XHR send (succeeds)', () => {
    cy.server()
    cy.route('POST', '/upload').as('upload');

    cy.uploadFile('Sample_data.xlsx', '[id=fileToUpload]')
    cy.get('form').then(form => mockNativeSubmitWithXhr(form))
    cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()

    cy.wait('@upload');
    cy.readFile('uploads/Sample_data.xlsx')
  })

  it('upload with native form submit (testing url has changed)', () => {
    cy.uploadFile('Sample_data.xlsx', '[id=fileToUpload]')
    cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()

    cy.url().should('eq', 'http://localhost:3000/upload')
    cy.readFile('uploads/Sample_data.xlsx')
  })
})
```

**Task to remove uploaded file between tests (modify '/cypress/plugins/index.js')**

```js
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    deleteFile: (path) => {
      if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
        fs.unlinkSync(path)
      }
      return null
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: The note “uses cy.url() instead of cy.route()” is confusing. cy.route is used to stub or alias the network call, not to assert url

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim - if you look at the the first two tests, they use an alias to wait (on the route). As an alternative, the third test uses the Cypress retry mechanism (via `.should()`) to wait for the url to change.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in something similar. The trick was not to check the route against a string but against a regular expression. Try this to match your POST route:

```
cy.route('POST', /showroom\/validate/).as('uploadShowroom');
// [...]
cy.wait('@uploadShowroom');
```

If you can see the the route is matching in cypress command log (yellow badge beside the route), it should do, what you want.

Answer (score -3):

Try to override default timeout of wait:

cy.wait('@uploadShowroom', {timeout: 10000);